# When can infinite graphs be partitioned into trees of a given minimum size

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, trees

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $0<\#V\leq \#\mathbb{N}$ and fix $n\leq \#V$.  When can $G$ be *partitioned* into $(V_1,E_1),\dots,(V_m,E_m)$ where $V= \cup_i \, V_i$, $\#V_i\geq n$ and $E_i$ contains *all* edges in $E$ between nodes in $V_i$, and each $(V_i,E_i)$ is a tree?

Comment: Does "partitioned" entail that the $E_i$ are pairwise disjoint (but the $V_i$ need not be)?

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Rather that both the $V_i$ and $E_i$ are pairwaise disjoint.  (In this case $\cup_i E_i $ need not cover $E$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Since ''partitioning'' has such strong connotations, it might be better to say that $V$ (and not $G$) is partitioned into disjoint parts $V_i$, such that each **induced subgraph** $G[V_i]$ is a tree and has at least $n$ vertices.